# Find functions :⟶ :⟶ such that ∘ is a 1-to-1 surjection ,  is not a surjection, and  is not 1-to-1.

Tags: real-analysis

Find functions :⟶ :⟶ such that ∘ is a 1-to-1 surjection ,  is not a surjection, and  is not 1-to-1.

I tried f(x) = arctan(x) and g(x) = tan (x), but not sure if that completely works.

Comment: What aren't you sure of?

Comment: Ive been told that arctan(x) is not defined over all real x, but I am not confident that is true

Comment: $\arctan$ is defined over the whole $\Bbb R$.  $\tan$ on the other hand isn't.  But you can modify $g$ just a bit to make this works.

Comment: How exactly should I modify g? would it be by adding something to tan?

Comment: $\arctan$ is defined over all reals but it's *range* is not the entire reals.  Which is *exactly* what you *want*.

Comment: You want $g(x)=\tan x$ for $x\in (-\frac \pi2, \frac\pi 2)$. For $x \not \in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac\pi 2)$ you can have $g$ be anything you want.  So you could do $g(x) = \tan x$ if $x\ne(2k+1)\frac \pi 2$ for any integer $k$ but $g(x) = 7$ for $x=(2k+1)\frac \pi 2$.  But since we don't care about any $x \not \in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ we could have $g(x) = \tan x$ if $x\in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ and $g(x) = x^3- \sqrt{27}$ for $x \not \in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ for all we care.....  $\arctan x$ will *never* be outside the range so we don't care what $g$ does outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can take, for instance,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{1-x^2}&\text{ if }x\in(-1,1)\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}-1}{2x}&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Clearly, $f$ is not injective and $g$ is not surjective (the range of $g$ is $(-1,1)$). But $g\circ f=\operatorname{Id}$.

Your example works too, if you extend $\tan$ to $\mathbb R$ (mapping the numbers of the form $\frac\pi2+n\pi$ into $0$, for instance).

Comment: Is f defined over all x? or just (-1, 1)

Comment: It's defined for all $x$. If $x\notin(-1,1)$, $f(x)=0$.